# Number of paths of length N inside a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Number of different paths (length N) between vertices x and y inside of a clique Kn or a bipartite graph Kn,n?

I am looking for simple paths. Therefore, in case I have n vertices N can be maximum n-1. For example, if n=4, we have maximum M = 3. For 3 we have 8 different paths, for 2 also 8 and for 1 only 6. I have done the calculations for bigger n as well, but I don't seem to catch a pattern.

Comment: This is unlikely to have a nice answer for bipartite : if x and y are in the same part of the graph, the result has to be $0$ when $N$ is even, and a lot when $N$ is odd. So this won't be a nice formula

Comment: What have you tried?  What progress have you made?  Have you tried calculating the answer for small values of $n$ and seeing if you can spot any pattern?  Have you tried looking up the resulting sequence at https://oeis.org/ ?  Also do you want the number of *simple* paths?

Comment: Hope my edits help.

Answer (score 0):

The following considers the number of paths of any length.

The case of the complete graph $K_n$ is simpler, so start with that. Fix the endpoints $x$ and $y$ of the path. Starting from the other end, how many ways do you have of choosing the next vertex to traverse to? What about the next one after that, how many choices do you have? Keep going, and you have it. To check your answer, you can see [A000522](https://oeis.org/A000522).

For the complete bipartite case $K_{n,n}$, you need to consider two cases: either $x$ and $y$ are in the same independent set (i.e., on the same side of the graph), or they are not. For these cases, it should be helpful to look at [A006041](https://oeis.org/A006041) and [A006040](https://oeis.org/A006040).